# How to consume JSON data into data extensions when third party is sending JSON into marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

Can any one please help me how to implement this in marketing cloud. since i am new to marketing cloud and I know how we can do that in salesforce service/sales cloud.

Scenario :

we are digital company and have stores all over the US and we want to send email receipts when the customer purchase any item in retail stores . once the order purchased and this data is storing into third party with store ID etc like that. Third party wants to send JSON data to Marketing and we have to consume that. we want to build a email template and consume that JSON data into template.

my thougt is :
**********what we are thinking here is we can create a template and create a triggered email with some triggered data extension. Through API call we want to trigger that email templates and data has to store in that triggered data extension. *******************

If marketing cloud is not allowing to consume JSON directly and we dont have ability to write a code inside marketing cloud.

My thought is to get the data into  salesforce sales/service cloud  (custom objects) and with the connector bring the data into marketing cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, marketing cloud can process JSON data using their "Guide Template Language" which is very similar to Mustache and Handlebars: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/guideTemplateLanguage.htm

It allows you to reference that object as a data source within your email and iterate through any number of items. We used this method as you described when I worked at my previous employer, another online retailer.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks for letting me know. if possible can you please share sample code which you have.